# How to I configure CentOS command sudo su with a password

Tags: linux, centos

I have disable accessibility on my CentOS server by using given username and password, I allow them to access server by using Public Key instead, but I noticed that every account can change to root permission just using "sudo su" without any password prompt. Is there any possible way to "enable/disable" password prompt from "sudo su" command?

Thanks

Comment: You really should include your sudo configuration in the question.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you've set something like that in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
% sudo ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

You have effectively given the users in the sudo group full unrestricted control over your system. Trying to deny them access to the su binary is as others have noted futile as they already have root privilege via sudo and membership of the group.

You should analyse the workflow of the users in the sudo group to determine which commands they need to run as root and use sudo to give them privilege access to those commands only. If necessary write scripts and give the sudo group access to run the script (make sure they don't have write access to it though) rather than the individual commands within it.

For example, users in my company which require to run specific commands are added to the `sudoers` file like so:

```
appadmin ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/rm -f /tmp/url_forever.log
noc ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh -x
nagios  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_rhcs
```

Comment: Really thanks for your reply and recommendation. That's really good ideas to classify user in different group with different and access permission. Let me try this.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it solved your issue.